# Can nodes that did not finish IBD import mempool using the importmempool rpc?

Tags: synchronization, mempool

Sometimes you might want to experiment with the mainnet mempool but unfortunately  your node has to finish IBD up to the latest chaintip for you to fill up your mempool.

Comment: Looks like the answer is in the question?

Comment: I’m not sure. I think that nodes will not ask for unconfirmed transactions from peers until they’ve caught up to the chaintip, but they might be able to use `importmempool`. I think that’s what the question is about.

Comment: Yes using the `importmempool` rpc

Comment: Do you mean can a node which has not finished IBD import a *current* mempool with `importmempool` (as in a mempool from a point in time far in the past compared to what the node is synchronized to)? If so, no, because all the mempool's transactions will be invalid (the importmempool RPC will succeed, but it won't actually import anything).

Comment: Ah, that’s a good point. Only transactions for which your node already knows about the UTXOs that the inputs are spending and the timelock has been reached will be valid.